# Prevent stroke in time travel scenario

Tags: time-travel, health

What can be done to prevent a deadly stroke of another person if the MC can time travelling back to 3 days before it.

Situation:

- Time travel is single time only, and 3 days only.
- The victim is a vice-president of a small lab. Age 50.
- MC is an intern in her lab, without a strong personal relation with her nor her contact details.
- The lab just opened again the day before her accident, after a long break.
- The country is a third-world country. Don't expect much from emergency health service.

Comment: hand her some aspirin?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I just read some info about stroke. It say aspirin is dangerous, because there are 2 kind of stroke, and aspirin will make 1 kind more severe.

Comment: well, if she's having the wrong type of stroke and she was going to die anyways, is she really worse off? Seriously, though, the best bet would be to somehow have her ALREADY AT THE HOSPITAL. Like fake a family illness and ask her to visit your dying "relative," so that way she's at least surrounded by doctors when she strokes out...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't think the stroke can happen exactly in the time window of visit, especially with fake news. Also, I am not that familiar with her. PS: Your joke is too close to be funny.

Comment: Sorry if I upset you, but it's not really a joke - if there's a 50% of the "right" kind of stroke, and she's certain to die if you DON'T intervene, then giving her the aspirin is absolutely the correct thing to do - you have a 50% chance of saving her and a 0% chance of "causing" her death (since you wouldn't be responsible anyhow).

Answer (score 2):

CVA's (Cerebral Vascular Accidents), which strokes fall under, can take many forms and the causes are equally varied. The thing is, the causes each take months, years, or decades to build up enough to cause them, so three days aren't going to make a whole lot of difference.

If the cause is a clot forming (which is the root cause for two types of stroke), then blood thinners could save her life. Most doctors would need to see the patient, but even in the third world, doctors should be trained to deal with that (getting them to care is not something I will debate, however)

If, however, you are travelling back in time. Maybe travelling further back will be more fruitful. Changing her diet a decade in the past will certainly prolong her life, but it would depend on you how to get her to do so.

But that brings me to one key question: why save this life? Surely the harsh reality hasn't evaded you? That people die all the time? Or perhaps even more curiously, what caused the need to save her, when far more influential people would certainly be more deserving?

Comment: Rational answer: practice for history changing: small change in near past and known condition, then wait for the butterfly. All those time travellers who go too far to the past do not know the risk.
Emotional answer: you save who you know, if the cause is considered avoidable.

Comment: @DTN Chaos theory and Murphey's law corroborate against you. On the practical side, you **cannot** know what effect your actions have on the plausible future, with our without time travel to perfect it. You don't know if it's something you did, didn't do, or something some random stranger did or didn't do that you did or didn't affect. Emotionally? You save them from a stroke and they choke on a meatball the next day. When it's someone's time, it's their time.

Comment: @DTN you're assuming the death is avoidable. Stopping a car crash is far easier (move her out of the way) than a medical incident like a stroke, especially since the risk factors might still be present (you're only shifting the time frame in which the stroke occurs)...